# Limit AWS S3 Bucket to only Lambda access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am using an AWS S3 bucket to hold configuration files for Java AWS Lambdas.  How do I configure the bucket to only allow access to any lambda function and nothing else?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you're trying to address an AWS service as a principal in an IAM policy, then you would use "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com" (or "s3.amazonaws.com", "ec2.amazonaws.com", etc.) However, in this case it's not the Lambda service that's relevant, I think, but the assumed IAM role under which your Lambda function is running because it's the invoked Lambda function itself that's retrieving the config from your S3 bucket (presumably).

Answer (score -1):

You need to add s3 bucket policy for account `123456789012` in region `us-east-1` -

```
   {
     "Id": "Policy1498253351771",
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
        {
           "Sid": "Stmt1498253327847",
           "Action": [
                        "s3:GetObject",
                        "s3:PutObject"
                     ],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/<prefix>",
           "Principal": {
           "AWS": [
                 "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:*"
                ]
           }
        }
    ]
 }
```

Above is a general policy for all lambda functions.

If you need to generate a more granular policy as per your usecase , you can try [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)

Comment: The policy shown allows the holder to invoke all Lambda APIs against all Lambda functions in AWS account 123456789012 in us-east-1. It doesn't help any Lambda function to retrieve objects from S3, or prevent non-Lambda functions from retrieving objects from a S3 bucket.

Comment: @jarmod , I have put a general one so that it can be taken as a reference while generating a policy from the link I shared . I have updated my policy as per your suggestion , please review it . thanks-